# Moving dataLabels for a Highcharts timeline all to one side

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to force a timeline series' dataLabels all to one side or the other?

I have a vertical timeline in Highcharts with several series (shown with "alternate: false"):
[image: a timeline of execution messages]

I would like to have, for instance, all of the "Sent for execution" labels on the left side.  The "alternate" option moves some of them, but not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer while asking the question.

Set the "distance" option to a negative value with "alternate" as false.  Here it is set to -100.

[image: a timeline of execution messages]